Blending Modes and Screenprints
I have created a complex image using brushes and one blending mode. This image is meant to be printed on a shirt - the printer needs a vector graphic. The problem is - I don't know exactly how to word this, so bare with me - that I don't know how to make each color "permanent". The color is contingent on the blending mode. I've tried flattening the image, using the pathfinder tool (divide) and then use the permanent color for the fill, rasterizing the image and then using live trace. It's really important that the image retains the detail which is why flattening and live trace didn't work. Divide just slows things down so much and eventually Illustrator crashes.
Here is a corner of the graphic.
What are my other options?
Is there any way that we can get the color separation from a rasterized graphic?


transparency flattener? No way to make your raster items vector though. Anyway this has nothing to do with screenprinting per see, no reason why the couldnt use a high res raster image. Yes you can get color separations from raster images, thats how it is typically done. But illustrator is not the right tool for that try Photoshop?

1. No. They do not "need" a vector graphic.
Screen prints do not need super High res, so you can even have a 100PPI raster image and you will be fine.
2. The problem in reality is. What is the printing system? Do you need color separations? or color selection.
A. If you are printing digitally, on an InkJet-based system, it is a lot better to deliver a flattened raster image. This is normally the case if you want only 1 or 10 shirts. (This is also the case for some sublimation systems)
B. If you are using silk screen print because you need a lot more, you have two other options.
a) Color separations, or CMYK; and again, a raster image is fine. (On this specific design I would recommend that you use a dithered pattern and not a halftone)
b) And if you are using silk print and transparent inks, your printer knows what he is doing, and you can be at the shop to supervise the print... (Only when all those conditions are met)
Then do the color separation manually. Basically send the blue shape and the gray shape in two different files or layers, as a solid black shape, with some registration marks.
The blending will be done during printing, with transparent inks, with a printer that knows what he is doing and you are there supervising the print, but do not expect it will work as intended.
c) Another option is to "fake" the blending and send that intersection as a new color and use a new ink. This way you can use solid inks instead of transparent ones.

Gray ink
Cyan-ish ink
Dark cyan-ish ink



And for the other question. Yes. An expert could extract the color separations from an uncompressed file. But it is always better to do it in the design phase, so you can extract all the details and not extract noise from the compression for example.
The first step for a design is to know the output, in this case, the printing method.

One method to extract the 3 colors from that sample could be using masks from a range of colors.
I am not using Ps here, but Corel PhotoPaint, but the basic idea is to choose one sample and define the range of similar colors to be selected.

Then, use that selection to generate a new layer and then convert it to black.

Now they can be used as solid plates for solid inks.

In Gimp you can use Select > By Color

In Ps... I do not use it anymore n_n

Thank you so much for your detailed response. That was really helpful. I ended up doing something similar but not exactly what you suggested because I was using PS and I'm not as familiar with the software. I ended up opening the image in PS. I used color selection to select the specific color and then I added it as a channel in the channels panel and then I converted that to a layer which gave me 3 color separations that I was able to put back into illustrator as 3 separate layers for the printer.

Ultimately this solution will not work because the pixelation really doesn't look right. So I have gone back and actually redesigned the design so that I can accommodate for the screen printers needs later on. Lesson learned, I will always be thinking about the final product when creating a design. Again, thanks so much for your help with this!
